# Will creating new objects help prevent concurrency issues inside a static method?

Tags: java, concurrency, static

I have this method that accepts an `OkHttp#response`:

```
public static Map<String, Object> getResponseBody(Response response) throws IOException {
    return new ObjectMapper()
            .readValue(response.body().string(),
                    new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {
                    });
}
```

From what I understand is that if multiple classes use the `getResponseBody`, I'll encounter big problems as they'll all be accessing the same `Response`.

Will it be solved if I do this?:

```
public static Map<String, Object> getResponseBody(Response response) throws IOException {
    ResponseBody responseBody = response.body();
    String responseString = responseBody.string();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Map<String, Object> map = mapper
            .readValue(responseString,
                    new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {
                    });
    return map;
}
```

Comment: *From what I understand is that if multiple classes use the getResponseBody, I'll encounter big problems as they'll all be accessing the same Response.* That is **not** correct.

Comment: Oh alright. May I ask for your correction?

Comment: Every thread that calls the `getResponseBody` method will provide a thread local `Response` instance. There is no shared **`static`** resource needing synchronization here. It looks thread safe.

Comment: local variables are not shared between threads for non-static and static methods. What they reference could be.

Comment: The second method does the same thing as the first method, but with named variables for some of the values. It doesn't change it's behaviour.

Comment: So just to confirm, the first code I showed is actually thread safe even though it directly uses the value passed from the parameter? I thought that the classes using the method would be "using the same instance of the method thus sharing everything inside".

Comment: Oh that's nice. Then I'll just go with the first one then. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments,

**tl;dr**: The first code I provided was thread safe all along.

> Every thread that calls the getResponseBody method will provide a
>   thread local Response instance. There is no shared static resource
>   needing synchronization here. It looks thread safe.
>
> Local variables are not shared between threads for non-static and
>   static methods. What they reference could be.
>
> The second method does the same thing as the first method, but with
>   named variables for some of the values. It doesn't change it's
>   behaviour.